# Get Progress status  of a long executed SP in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have  `SP` in SqlServer (2005+) which uses `cursor` and do some stuff (on 10,000 rows)

I need something like a progress bar ( to see in my c# **web site**.).

I can take the 10,000 divided by 100 in such that each 1000 records it will do ( using sql print command) : `process of another 1000 is done !!!`

But I want to catch that print ( each **new** print) in my asp.net  web site.

how can I catch the print commands / or is there any better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process we used to implement something similiar is a little more complicated, but it does work.

We created a webservice that had a number of methods, for example;

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true), WebMethod]
public void StartUpdate(string reference)

[WebMethod]
public ProcessStatus GetProcessStatus(string reference)
```

A call to the asynch webmethod would start the process running and passed in a reference number to identify itself. This in turn called a stored procedure which used an update on iterations of the cursor to update another table with 'reference', 'count' and 'status'

The GetProcessStatus would then pass this reference in and pass back the current count and status. If the status was completed, we could move on, alternatively, you could use the 'count' at this point to update the status. An example of this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.JavaScript.Text = string.Format("<script>setTimeout(\"{0}\", {1});</script>", 
            this.Page.GetPostBackClientEvent(this.btnRefresh, ""), 3000);


        ProcessStatus status= Class.GetProcessStatus(reference);

        lblCount.Text = status.Count.ToString();



        if (import.Status == (int)ProcessStatus.Status.Complete)
        {
            Globals.GoUrl("/Import/File/Map.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when  a step of progress has occurred, Does it being pushed to the asp.net? or the asp.net in a timer - query the value ...?

Comment: Just call the second method on a standard asp page using a timer, added an update above.

Comment: If `StartUpdate` is using a transaction for the update,  `GetProcessStatus` will not be able to query second table at all.

Comment: How does this work in the OP's scenario of a SP with PRINT statements?